# What does "KeyError: '(insert IP)'" mean?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I am working with the Violent Python book and there is an error that is stopping me from moving past the first nmap build (pg 40-41). Using Ubuntu 14.04 on a VM. I am inputting 'python nmapScan.py -H 10.50.60.125 -p 21, 1720' in to the terminal.

```
import nmap
import optparse

def nmapScan(tgtHost,tgtPort):
    nmScan = nmap.PortScanner()
    nmScan.scan(tgtHost,tgtPort)
    state=nmScan[tgtHost]['tcp'][int(tgtPort)]['state']
    print "[*] " + tgtHost + " tcp/"+tgtPort +" "+state

def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage %prog '+\
                                   '-H <target host> -p <target port>')
    parser.add_option('-H', dest='tgtHost', type='string',\
                      help='specify target host')
    parser.add_option('-p', dest='tgtPort', type='string',\
                      help='specify target port[s] separated by comma')

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    tgtHost = options.tgtHost
    tgtPorts = str(options.tgtPort).split(',')

    if (tgtHost == None) | (tgtPorts[0] == None):
        print parser.usage
        exit(0)
    for tgtPort in tgtPorts:
        nmapScan(tgtHost, tgtPort)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the error:

```
File "nmapScan.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
File "nmapScan.py", line 21, in main
    nmapScan(tgtHost, tgtPort)
File "nmapScan.py", line 7, in nmapScan
    state = nmScan[tgtHost]['tcp'][int(tgtPort)]['state']
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/nmap/nmap.py", line 567, in __getitem__
KeyError:'10.50.60.125'
```

Comment: Sorry, but it works fine for me. Try adding a few debugging print statements, such as `print nmap.all_hosts()`. Some nmap info is at http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/.

Comment: Are you actually asking what `KeyError` means? If so, see the [python docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError). If you instead mean "Why does my PortScanner object from python-nmap not contain the host I'm trying to scan", please update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `KeyError` in nmap means the `ip` was unreachable. You should verify the ip is actually up.

If you are not always sure if the host will be up or not you need a `try/except`:

```
try:
    state = nmScan[tgtHost]['tcp'][int(tgtPort)]['state']
except KeyError as e:
   print(e)
   return
```

Answer (score 1):

This host `10.50.60.125` is not reachable.

```
ping 10.50.60.125
PING 10.50.60.125 (10.50.60.125): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
```

Try with some reachable host like : `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Thank you guys so much. The book's example is out of date

Answer (score 0):

this is because that no information of ports was scaned by nmap,
you can check with

```
nmScan = nmap.PortScanner()
data = nmScan.scan(tgtHost,tgtPort)
print(data.get(tgtHost))
```

and you will find that the output values is empty

from  the source cod, we can know that: 
`nmScan[tgtHost]` is equal to `data.get(tgtHost)[tgtHost]`

the better way is obtain information with `data.get(tgtHost)[tgtHost]`  or `data.get(tgtHost).get(tgtHost, {})`